# Склонение женских фамилий на -а

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилия Бандера по падежам, если носитель фамилии женщина: Бандера Светлана - Бандере Светлане?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mr7.ru/articles/20617/

Склонение фамилий на А

Самый сложный случай – склонение фамилий с конечным а. Здесь имеет значение, какая буква стоит перед а – гласная или согласная, падает ли на эту гласную ударение, какого происхождения фамилия.

1) Все фамилии, кончающиеся на а, которому предшествуют ГЛАСНЫЕ (чаще всего у или и), несклоняемы: Галуа, Моруа, Делакруа, Моравиа, Эриа, Эредиа, Гулиа.

2) Не склоняются фамилии французского происхождения на УДАРНОЕ "а": Дюма, Тома, Ферма, Петипа.

Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков) склоняются: Митта – Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой; сюда относятся: Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.

3) Все фамилии, кончающиеся на НЕУдАРНОЕ "а" после СОГЛАСНЫХ, склоняются: Рибера – Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Окуджава и др.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Бандера - неударный "а" после согласного, мужская (и женская) фамилия склоняется по образцу существительных 1-го склонения ж. и м. рода.

Пример: "Как рассказал Степан Бандера,  вчера в Торонто не стало его тетки - Леси Бандеры".

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно, склоняется – и женская, и мужская.

Answer (score 0):

Склоняется, причем и мужская и женская. По образцу "вера", "холера", "манера". 
Бандера, Бандеры, Бандере, Бандеру, Бандерой, о Бандере.

Вообще на самом деле никаких *практических* сложностей в правилах склонения фамилиях нет. Склонять надо все, что только в принципе может склоняться, - за очень редкими исключениями (французские и некоторые односложные фамилии - на а). Иногда встречающиеся рекомендации не склонять финские, японские и некоторые другие фамилии весьма спорны. Иногда бывают сложности с выбором типа склонения (фамилии типа Жемчужина или Лошадь). Все остальное - далеко за пределами повседневной практики.

Подробности у Vera.